# D3 selector on DOM element using inequality comparison on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

My Dom contains the following svg element

```
       <circle cx="50326.72265625" cy="9764.853515625" r="300"  
       ipaddress="1.4.142.99" deleted="false" voltage="4.236859" 
       version="klo">
       </circle>
```

I need to select all circles having their voltage > 3

Can someone shed some light on this please ?

Answer (score -2):

```
d3.slectAll('circle').filter( function () {
    return +d3.select(this).attr('voltage') > 3.0;
});
```